# jWebSocket client on Android not connecting to local server

Tags: android, client, websocket

I'm trying to start a very simple jWebSocket Client on Android and connect it to my local server. I'm using the JWC class from the demo together with jWebSocket 1.0 beta 8 and Android 4.0.3, my code looks like this:

```
import org.jwebsocket.api.WebSocketClientEvent;
import org.jwebsocket.api.WebSocketClientTokenListener;
import org.jwebsocket.api.WebSocketPacket;
import org.jwebsocket.client.token.BaseTokenClient;
import org.jwebsocket.kit.WebSocketException;
import org.jwebsocket.token.Token;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import cased.smids.communication.JWC;

public class TasksActivity extends Activity implements WebSocketClientTokenListener {
   Spinner spinner;
   Button btn_Start;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        JWC.init();

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_Task);
        btn_Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Start);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        this,
                        R.array.Tasks,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn_Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View src) {
                switch (src.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btn_Start:
                        if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Connect")) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("connecting manually...");
                                JWC.open();
                            } catch (WebSocketException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("* opening... ");
        try {
            JWC.addListener(this);
            JWC.open();
        } catch (WebSocketException ex) {
            System.out.println("* exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        System.out.println("* closing... ");
        try {
            JWC.close();
            JWC.removeListener(this);
        } catch (WebSocketException ex) {
            System.out.println("* exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void processClosed(WebSocketClientEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("closed");
    }

    public void processOpened(WebSocketClientEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("opened");
    }

    public void processOpening(WebSocketClientEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("opening");
    }

    public void processPacket(WebSocketClientEvent arg0, WebSocketPacket arg1) {
        System.out.println("packet");
    }

    public void processReconnecting(WebSocketClientEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("reconnecting");
    }

    public void processToken(WebSocketClientEvent arg0, Token arg1) {
        System.out.println("token");
    }
}
```

so basically it's just a spinner and a button. For now, all I want to do is connect to my local jWebSocketServer. The demo-app (the .apk package from the website, if I import the code eclipse tells me to remove many "@Overwrite" before it compiles the code - after that same "bug" occurs) works with my server so it has to be the code. Right now all I get is "connecting..." and about 0.1s later "closed". Every time.

btw. the app has the right INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE so that shouldn't be a problem.

i will be grateful for any help.

Cheers

Comment: your wrote that you finally found an exception, but how/where did you find the exception "NetworkOnMainThreadException"? is there any "hidden" logfile or secret "debug mode switch"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, BaseTokenClient.open() is catching all exceptions and doing nothing about it (silent fail). In my  case - NetworkOnMainThreadException. Mystery solved.